# SignalR : create own id factory

Tags: signalr

I know that in previous versions of signalR I have ability to manage connectionId values using **IConnectionIdFactory** or  **IConnectionIdGenerator**. Now for this purpose **HubPipelineModule** exists but I have no idea how to use.Can anybody share link or provide simple example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't choose a connection id (that interface has been long removed from SignalR)  but you can associate a UserId with one or more connections using an IUserIdProvider (by default it'll use the current' user name).

This sample shows how you register and author one of these:
https://github.com/DamianEdwards/SignalR-2.x-demo/blob/master/SignalR2x/Web/Startup.cs#L17

https://github.com/DamianEdwards/SignalR-2.x-demo/blob/master/SignalR2x/Web/Startup.cs#L28